# how i share audio in telegram

Tags: java, android, telegram

i write this code but when i select chat in telegram for share audio intent not work and write this error "unsupported attachment"

```
File file = null;
            try {
                file = new File(String.valueOf(getAssets().openFd("bear.mp3")));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("audio/*");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share,
                    "به اشتراک گذاشتن فایل"));
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add following flag to share intent;

```
share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```